# Sanskrit Names of Naivedyams

Tags: sanskrit, prasad

I was searching for Sanskrit names of various naivedyams offered in our rituals (in all regions and traditions) like pulihora, chakra pongali, and various fruits and juices etc. Is there any book that describes all of them? If so what is it? I would also like to request to post the names with pictures so that it will be clear.

Comment: Pure Sanskrit questions are not encouraged here.

Comment: Which prasadams you want Sanskrit names? Asking for all would make the question too broad.

Answer (score 3):

You will find few such names in the following verses from the Devi Bhagavatam, Book 8, Chapter 24. Here it is describing which are the special food offerings that please Devi if offered on particular days, Tithis, Nakshatras etc.

> 21-42. O Muni! On the above tithis, if one forms daily Homas, as
>   stated in the Pûjâ Chapter, the Devî becomes very pleased. The
>   articles corresponding to the tithi as mentioned above destroy all the
>   evils and inauspicious omens. On Sunday, it is a rule to give an
>   offering of Pâyasam (a food prepared of rice, milk, and sugar). On
>   Monday, the milk; on Tuesday, the nice plantains; on Wednesday, the
>   freshbutter; on Thursday, the gud or sugarcandy, Friday, the white
>   sugar, and on Saturday, it is a rule to give the clarified butter of
>   cow’s milk. Now hear what should be offered on the Naksattras. The
>   following are the Naivedyas given to each of the Naksattras, in due
>   order, from As’vinî :-- Clarified butter (ghee), sesamum (Til), sugar,
>   curd, milk, **Kilâtak (Mâlâi, milk), Dadhikûrchi (Mâlâi Curd), Modaka
>   (a kind of sweetmeat, a confection) Phenikâ, Ghrita Mandaka, a sort of
>   sweet meat of wheaten flour and gur, Vatapattra, Ghritapura (Ghior),
>   Vataka, Kharjura juice (of the datepalm), a sort of sweet meat of Gur
>   and gram, honey,** S’ûrana, Gur Prithuka, grapes, datepalms, Chârakâs,
>   Apûpa, Navanîta (fresh butter), mudga, modaka, and Mâtulinga. Now hear
>   what are given in the Viskambha and the other Yogas. The World Mother
>   becomes very much pleased when one offers to Her the following things
>   :-- Gur, honey, ghee, milk, curd, **Takra, apûpa**, fresh butter,
>   **Karkatî,** Kusmânda, Modaka, Panasa, plantain, Jambu (rose-apple), mangoe, sesamum, oranges, Dâdima, (pomegranate) Vadarî (Jujube) the
>   Dhâtrî (Âmalaki) fruit, **Pâyasa**, Prithuka, gram, cocoanut, Jambîra.
>   Kaseru, and S’ûrana. The auspicious events occur when these are
>   offered. The intelligent persons have thus decided to give the above
>   on Viskambha and the other Yogas. Now hear :-- I will describe the
>   things that are offered on the respective Karanas :--
>   **Kamsâra, Mandaka, Phenî, Modaka, Vatapattraka, Ladduka, Ghritapûra,** Til (Sesamun), curd, ghee, and honey. These are to be
>   offered devotedly to the Devî on the respective Karanas. Now I will
>   describe to you the other offerings very pleasing to the Devî

I have highlighted few of those names.